# iOS Calabash using specific scheme from the command line?

Tags: ios, cucumber, calabash, calabash-ios

Is there a way to configure calabash to run a set of tests using a specific target or scheme for an iOS app?

My specific use case uses cucumber to run the tests but I assume that if there is an option to configure calabash schemes it should work for any tools...

Thanks!

Comment: Calabash does not have schemes.  Are you asking, "How do I target a different application with Calabash?" Are you asking about cucumber profiles?  Maybe you are asking about how to build an application from the command line with xcodebuild?

Comment: Ok I can clarify.. I am trying to target a specific scheme/target... like the `myapp-cal` scheme described in the documentation https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Tutorial%3A--Creating-a-cal-Target. However I need to be able to do this from the command line, and using cucumber as you mentioned... but cucumber profiles don't seem to allow targets or schemes

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your Xcode scheme in the .xcodeproj to have a phase that calls cucumber after setting `'APP_BUNDLE_PATH'` in your environment to the location the scheme built your IPA at. You could then invoke that scheme using `'xcrun xcodebuild --scheme SCHEMENAME'`.

To execute a specific test in cucumber, you could do:

```
cucumber -r path/to/file.feature:<line number of specific scenario>
```